# Shopping cart basket

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I have a piece of code like this:

```
public function index(){
        $products = session()->get('cart')->items;
        // dd($products);
        return view('basket', compact('products'));
    }
```

and `blade.php`:

[image: blade.php]

Error:

```
Trying to get property 'items' of non-object
```

Comment: Maybe `session()->get('cart')` return null

Comment: Can you var_dump(session()->get('cart'))  and see what you get?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? And have you checked `dd($products);`?

Comment: @Hiren Gohel 
Laravel Framework 5.7.15

Comment: @rs007
error: Trying to get property 'items' of non-object

$products = session()->get('cart')->items;

Comment: @AlisherADM: `dd(session()->get('cart'));` Remove first `items` from it and check it. Is it gives you the result?

Comment: @AlisherADM, just session()->get('cart') and dont access property $items just yet, try to see if it returns null

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `$products = session()->get('cart')->items;` you should hanle if your session doesn't have any products or not so you should do this:

in php-7

```
$products = $session()->get('cart')->items?? [];
```

in php-5

```
$cart = $session()->get('cart');
$products = $cart ? $cart->items : [];
```

So if the session is empty the `$products` will be an empty array or it will have the items.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(session()->has('cart'))
        {
            $products = session()->get('cart')->items;
        }
        else
        {
            $products = 'nothing';
        }
```

I could decide